# HorizontalListView inside ListView-NullpointerException

Tags: android, android-listview, horizontal-scrolling, horizontallist

I am trying to implement HorizontalListView(http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) inside Listview. But My application closes and Logcat show Exception in Main and NullPointer Exception.
What I tried was.. My main activity uses xml containing listview. It calls a custom adapter which extends a base adapter. This cumstom adapter inflates a xml conataining HorizontalListview and getView method calls another adapter. This final Adapter calls an xml which will fill each row item.
The application works fine till adapter 1 call..As i tried ninflating another normal xml(containing textview) and it worked.

My application is having dynamic number of elements in both horizontal as well as vertical direction thats why i ahve to implement this approach.

Any suggestions.
Can provide the code if anyonw wants.

This is my getview method of first adapter

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        View ret=convertView;
         if (convertView==null)
        ret = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
         HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView)ret.findViewById(R.id.listview1);

         listview.setAdapter(madapter);
        return ret;
}
```

Comment: Post the logcat output

Comment: Sorry, couldn't update it but I got the solution, I have to pass my main activity's context to my second adapter. And it worked.